# listview animation fadeout then adding new row

Tags: android, listview, animation

hey guys Im trying to make a fadeout animation in my to do list app in android. I have this code

```
public void removeToDo(){
myItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,  View view, final int position, long id) {



        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ALPHA, 0);

        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                items.remove(position);
                itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        anim.start();

        return true;
    }
});

}
```

yeah its fading out beautifully but the problem is when I added a new Item it reuses the row that fades out the item already so the result is that I will have a new row upon adding a new Item but without text on it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6wPz.jpg

please help Im just a newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. `ObjectAnimator` not reliable, Use `Animation` instead of this.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {
                final Adapter adapter = (Adapter) parent.getAdapter();

                Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                fadeOut.setDuration(500);
                fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        adapter.pointItems.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                view.startAnimation(fadeOut);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks man it works. I also some comments that I can do it in RecyclerView and use ObjectAnimator?

Comment: I`am used only animation and recommend it to you.